# Merge strings in a list until conditions are met

Tags: python, string, merge

Given a list of strings, I'm trying to merge a string to the next one until two conditions are met, namely a % sign and a integer followed by a point is present in the string.

I undertook a project in which I locate relevant pages then extract and clean text from PDF files.

I'm a bit stuck at the cleaning phase. I have a specific list of strings that have been located, filtred and extracted, and I would like to merge a string from this list to the next until it meets two conditions :

- a percentage sign is present in the string
- an integer followed by a . is present in the string

For example this list :

- `['A.1 Environmentally', '3.3 Manufacture of low', 'carbon technologies', 'C29.1 0 0% 100%']`

Should become this list:

- `['A.1 Environmentally', '3.3 Manufacture of low carbon technologies C29.1 0 0% 100%']`

This is the function I wrote to try and achieve this :

```
def merge_strings(lst):
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst)-1:
        if "%" in lst[i] and "." in lst[i]:
            i += 1
            continue
        lst[i] = lst[i] +' '+ lst[i+1]
        lst.pop(i+1)
    return lst
```

But this results in this:

- `['A.1 Environmentally 3.3 Manufacture of low carbon technologies C29.1 0 0% 100%']`

Comment: Could you explain how you're getting to the expected result? it doesn't seem to work according to the conditions you formulated...

Comment: For the example: your `i` stays `0` throughout, and in each loop you merge the first item with the second and `pop` the second, until `lst` has exactly 1 item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = r'\.\d'

def merge_strings(lst):
    start = 0
    end = 0

    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        if "%" in lst[i]:
            end = i
            for idx in range(start, end):
                lst[start] += f" {lst[start+1]}"
                lst.pop(start+1)
            i = start
            end = start
        elif re.search(pattern, lst[i]):
            start = i
        else:
            end += 1
            
        i+= 1
```

I think this is what you might be looking for. It works for the test case that you have given.